# Is it technically incorrect to speak English using speech sounds of native language(which is not English)?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, esl

Consonants "t" and "p" are not unvoiced in my native language, which is Hindi. So I pronounce "Paint" with voiced "p" and "t", is it technically correct? It is acceptable, I know. But is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: in accordance with rules of English pronunciation.

Comment: there is a double negative in your first statement. Is that intentional? It confuses whether you do or do not voice those consonants. Would you please edit to make the question clearer?

Comment: If voiced, P and T become B and D, which are different phonemes in English, so it will end up sounding like entirely different words, causing confusion.

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) - The voiceless plosives /p/, /t/, /k/ are always unaspirated in Indian English. Thus "pin" is pronounced [pɪn] in Indian English but [pʰɪn] in most other dialects. In native Indian languages (except Tamil), the distinction between aspirated and unaspirated plosives is phonemic, and the English stops are equated with the unaspirated rather than the aspirated phonemes of the local languages. The same is true of the voiceless postalveolar afficate /tʃ/.

Comment: Do whatever you want. Have you heard a Scot or a Welsh speak? What about cockney? It's your English. Generally, I don't care how you speak it, as long as it is proper English with some acceptable variants/deviation. Anyway, Indian accent is kinda nice to listen to - very soothing to the ears.

Comment: An accent cannot be correct or incorrect. An accent is an accent. My accent is not more correct than yours. At best it might be closer to RP, but that one is but an accent itself.

Comment: Blessed Geek, don't you mean a Welsh **person**?

Answer (score 2):

It means you speak English with a 'foreign' (to English) accent, rather than the standard English, which is taught as a standard to aim for in schools, and generally used for international business. This applies equally to British and American English, both of which have 'standard' forms.

The narrower the range of the people you want to communicate to, the less important it is to use standard forms. The wider it is, the more important it is.

Answer (score 2):

Well, pronunciation is a tricky subject. But being technically correct or incorrect has nothing to do with your pronunciation. It would sound not native but would still be correct. If you were talking about standard American or British English, than the way you speak might not be considered standard, but would still be correct.